# Regular expression to capture groups "*2*2*2" OR "*2*2*2*2"?

Tags: java

```
String input = "This is a *2*2*2 test";
String input1 = "This is also a *2*2*2*2 test";
```

How do I write a regex that captures either (*2*2*2) or (*2*2*2*2) ?

Comment: `*2` repeated any number of times, or only 3 or 4 times?

Comment: We can probably help you better if you show us things that it shouldn't capture, too.  BTW, what do you mean "capture"?  You mean group it?

Comment: You're only looking to capture specifically stars and twos in that order?

Comment: [What, specifically, have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: `.*` will match both of those. So what do you actually _want_ ? What do you want to not capture, and what outputs are you trying to extract?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((\\*2){3,4})");
```

Explanation: The `\\` inserts a single `\` into the pattern; this escapes the `*` which would otherwise be a wildcard character match. The character sequence "*2" is then matched exactly 3 or 4 times. The parentheses around the whole thing makes it a capture group.

Comment: Why make the whole thing a capturing group? `(?:\*2){3,4}` should work as well.

Comment: @arshajii - OP asked about capturing the entire pattern.

Comment: The entire regex itself will be captured without putting a capturing group around the whole thing. Otherwise, every regex would need a capturing group around it.

Comment: @arshajii - Good point. However, if this were embedded in a larger regex, . . .

Answer (score 1):

You can try the regular expression:

```
(\*2){3,4}
```

In ahother hand, you need to use a constant of Pattern for avoid recompiled the expression every time, something like that:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("(\\*2){3,4}");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "This is a *2*2*2 or *2*2*2*2 test";
    Matcher matcher = REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
*2*2*2
*2*2*2*2
```